# Which power series with integer coefficients have multiplicative inverses?

Tags: ring-theory

Note that by this I mean Z[[x]], a commutative ring with 1 and integer coefficients.

I've been racking my mind over this question. Considering the neutral multiplicative power here is 1 and thus is an inverse of itself, wouldn't all elements of the set have a multiplicative inverse of x^-i, i being the power of Z[[x]]? Or considering there are no negative powers in the original R[[x]], would there be no elements with inverses?

Comment: Think about what happens to degree when you compute a product in your ring. What does this tell you about invertible elements?

Comment: The degree of the product x^m and x^n is x^m+n? Does this mean any invertible element would have to have negative exponents too?

Comment: If you can do long division of polynomials, in the manner taught in high-school, then you can do long division of power series. Just write the series in •ascending* powers of your variable. The process is exactly the same as what you already know, but it doesn’t usually end. Once you do a few such divisions, you see what the answer to your question is. Of course you already know that $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots$

Answer (score 3):

If you have an invertible power series $\sum a_ix^i$ in $R[[X]]$, with inverse $\sum b_jx^j$, then $a_0b_0 = 1$, so $a_0$ has to be invertible in $R$.

Conversely, if $a_0$ is invertible in $R$, you can divide by its inverse to reduce the problem to the case of a series starting with $1$, and then apply the power series $(1+z)^{-1} = 1 - z + z^2 - z^3 + z^4 \ldots$ with $z = \sum_{i \ge 1} a_ix^i$ to find its inverse.

Comment: But considering the coefficients in this case can only be integers, wouldn't 1 be the only a and b that can work?

Comment: in $\Bbb Z$, $1$ and $-1$ are the only invertible elements, if that's what you are asking. Then in $\Bbb R$, inevrtible elements are nonzero elements.

Comment: Right. But for this question, we're looking for elements of the set Z[[x]]*, where all coefficients are integers. Would this mean that a = 1 and a = -1 are the only solutions?

Comment: If you think that $\Bbb Z[[X]]^*$ has only two elements, then no.

Comment: The invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]^*$ are precisely the elements with constant coefficient 1 or -1.