# Inverse of the $\Delta$ function has integer Fourier coefficients

Tags: modular-forms

Consider the cusp form $\Delta$ of weight 12 defined as:
$$\Delta=2^{-6}3^{-3}(E_2^3-E_3^2)$$
where $E_2$ and $E_3$ are the normalised Eisenstein series that are modular forms of weight 4 and 6 respectively and are given as:
$$E_2(z)=1+240\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_3(n)e^{2\pi inz}$$
$$E_3(z)=1-504\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_5(n)e^{2\pi inz}.$$
Here $\sigma_3(n)$ denotes the sum of the 3rd powers of the divisors of $n$, whereas $\sigma_5(n)$ denotes the sum of the 5th powers.

It is a standard result that $\Delta$ has integer Fourier coefficients. I wish to prove that that $1/\Delta$ has integer Fourier coefficients. I have encountered proofs which use this fact without proving it. Is it obvious?

Comment: Obvious enough that it's also used implicitly [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/532179/75794).

Comment: [Relevant topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723549/)

Comment: For those who need to know how $\Delta$ has integer coefficients, look at (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315511/prove-that-coefficients-of-cusp-form-are-always-in-mathbbz?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard geometric series computation shows that
$$ \dfrac{1}{1-X} = 1 + X + X^2 + \cdots.$$
Thus
$$ \dfrac{1}{q(1-X)} = \dfrac{1}{q} + \dfrac{X}{q} + \dfrac{X^2}{q} + \cdots.$$
Now apply this with 
$$ X = - \sum_{n = 2} ^{\infty} \tau(n) q^{n-1},$$
to compute $1/\Delta$.

Since $X$ has integral $q$-expansion coefficients, so do all its powers,
and hence so does $1/\Delta.$

Comment: Can someone explain how $\mid X \mid  = \mid - \sum_{n = 2} ^{\infty} \tau(n) q^{n-1} \mid  < 1$ so that the geometric series formula works?